# Exercise with Reactive Programming

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactive

I'm learning reactive programming with RxJS, and I have the following exercice:

- It starts with an empty array
- When the application starts, a new Date () is inserted into the array
- Each time you click on the screen, a value is entered at the end of the array with the date on which the click was made
- When the array has 3 values, do the calculation:
       (array [2] .value () + array [1] .value () - array [0])% 2
- If the result = 0, then print 'Result valid'
- Else, nothing.
- After do the calculation of the array, if a new element is added, the first element must be removed, move the others and put this new element at the end of the array.

I tried with the declarative way and reactive way, but the reactive way does not convince me that it's really reactive, since it contains many if / else and a lot of logic in the subscriber.

My question is:
In the function exercise_1__v2_reactive , is the code according to the reactive programming?

```
function exercise_1__v1_imperative() {
    let values: Array<Date> = [];
    values.push(new Date());

    document.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
        values.push(new Date());
        console.log(`values: `, values);

        if (values.length === 3) {
            let a = values[0].valueOf(), b = values[1].valueOf(), c = values[2].valueOf();
            let result = (c - b + a) % 2;
            console.log(`result: `, result);

            if (result === 0) {
                console.log(`Resultado valido: `, result);
            }

            values.shift();
        }
    });
}

function exercise_1__v2_reactive() {
    const newDate$ = of(new Date().valueOf());
    // newDate$.subscribe(console.log);

    const clickDate$ = fromEvent(document, `click`).pipe(
        map(x => new Date())
    );

    clickDate$.pipe(
        startWith(new Date()),
        scan<Date, Array<Date>>((acc, value) => {
            if (acc.length === 3) {
                acc.shift();
            }

            acc.push(value);
            return acc;
        }, [])
    ).subscribe(values => {
        console.log(values);

        if (values.length === 3) {
            let a = values[0].valueOf(), b = values[1].valueOf(), c = values[2].valueOf();
            let result = (c - b + a) % 2;
            console.log(`result: `, result);

            if (result === 0) {
                console.log('Resultado valido: ', result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @zero298 question updated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your `exercise_1__v2_reactive` function is fine from rxjs perspective with little improvement. You need not use `startWith` and use `filter` operator to only emit an array of length 3. I would propose like this:

```
function exercise_1__v2_reactive() {
  fromEvent(document, 'click')
                  .pipe(
                    mapTo(new Date()),
                    scan((acc: any, val) => {

                        if (acc.length === 3) {
                          acc.shift();
                        }
                        acc.push(val);
                        return acc;
                    }, []),
                    filter(a => a.length === 3),
                    //Tap is just to check what my array is - But its not needed
                    tap(console.log),
                    map(values => {
                        const result = (values[2].valueOf() - values[1].valueOf() + values[0].valueOf()) % 2;

                        console.log(`result: `, result);

                        if (result === 0) {
                            return 'Result Valid';
                        }
                        return 'Result Invalid';
                    })
                  ).subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Notice I am not using `startWith` and also mapping the final outcome with the desired string. It is up to the need what you want to project the final outcome.

Comment: Interesting answer. I have a question on the scan: maybe another operator can be used? I was thinking about using buffers, can it work?

Comment: @Marlonchosky I doubt that buffers operators could be helpful here because buffer operators emit the buffered items as per the buffer condition. Although you can make use of it but you will end up with imperative code inside your operator pipeline or ins subscribe. The challenge would be to keep track of the last two dates. I think `scan` operator is your best friend here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I thought that with buffers I could emit every time I have 3 dates, but the problem then would be how saving the last 2 dates

Answer (score 0):

After researching the RxJS operators, the solution can be done with the `bufferCount` operator, passing it as parameters `bufferCount(3, 1)`, the second parameter indicates when to start a new buffer, which in this case, would be every click is done:

```
fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  map(_ => new Date()),
  startWith(new Date()),
  bufferCount(3, 1),
  map(([a, b, c]) => (c.valueOf() - b.valueOf() + a.valueOf()) % 2),
  tap(val => console.log('TAPPING: ', val)),
  filter(x => x === 0)
).subscribe(valid => {
  console.log('Result valid')
});
```

The solution is in this url:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-q3aneg